# Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/www/loveIt/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a problem with gunicorn. I [followed](https://habr.com/ru/post/501414/) this guide to run website hosting on my raspberry on debian. But I got this error:

> gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/www/loveIt/env/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory

I don't understand why it don't create gunicorn. I watched a lot of guides but no one helped me. Here is my gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=anton
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/loveIt
ExecStart=/var/www/loveIt/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 5 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          lulu.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And this is my gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

What I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: this will help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/gunicorn-service-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem on which I spent several hours with one link.I'm very grateful

Comment: Happy to help you❤️